# Retrieving relation of users and usermeta table from wordpress database using Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, eloquent, laravel-5

I am trying to access a user's `first_name` in my custom script which uses Eloquent to retrieve data (in Laravel 5 actually )

So,

Here is how i defined relationship (one to many ) // is that correct ?? Wp Guru may tell

In `User` Model, i have

```
public function usermeta() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Usermeta','user_id');
    }
```

In my `UserController` I have

```
 $users = \App\User::with('usermeta')->get();
```

And here how i access it in my views

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
      <tr>
            <th>{{$user->ID}}</th>
            <th>{{$user->usermeta->/*how to access particular meta key here*/}}</th>
            <th>{{$user->display_name}}</th>
      </tr>
@endforeach
```

So the problem is, everything works except when i try to access the `usermeta` relation, I'm actually not sure how to query a particular meta key's value by passing `meta_key` as an argument either in my relation or in foreach loop

I tried directly accessing  like `$user->usermeta->first_name` but that is incorrect for sure.

How can i retrive the `meta_value` from a `usermata` table in wordpress database using Eloquent Model?

**Edit 1**

trying the accessor method approach by @james-flight 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30871346/1679510
It works when i know the position of the record in [collection object](http://echome.in/user.html).

```
if ($usermeta->count() > 0) {
    return $usermeta[0]->meta_value;
}
```

However, since the `meta_key` can be anything, and may reside at other position.
if the `meta_key` is `first_name` , then `$usermeta[1]` have the array of column values for it, and so on.

```
 if ($usermeta->count() > 0) {
        return $usermeta[/*This cannot be hard code */]->meta_value;
    }
```

How to get it resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usermeta is a hasMany relationship, which means Eloquent will return a Collection object containing multiple Usermeta models.

You could instead do this:

```
{{ $user->usermeta[0]->first_name }}
```

Or this:

```
@foreach($user->usermeta as $usermeta)
    {{ $usermeta->first_name }}
@endforeach
```

**Edit**

To use `meta_key` and `meta_value` as a key value pair, you could write an accessor method on `User`:

```
public function getMetaValue($key) {
    $usermeta = $this->usermeta->filter(function ($usermeta) use ($key) {
        return $usermeta->meta_key === $key;
    });

    if ($usermeta->count() > 0) {
        return $usermeta[0]->meta_value;
    }
}
```

And then access in blade like so:

```
{{ $user->getMetaValue('first_name') }}
```

This will get slow at high volume though.

**Edit 2**

The above method should in fact be as follows, to ensure the array key exists:

```
public function getMetaValue($key) {
    $usermeta = $this->usermeta->filter(function ($usermeta) use ($key) {
        return $usermeta->meta_key === $key;
    });

    if ($usermeta->count() > 0) {
        return $usermeta->first()->meta_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: yup, i seen those collections in `dd($users)` and was wondering how to access that array.
so while using `$user->usermeta[0]->first_name` that still returns  null :-(

Comment: Can you see the usermeta properties that you are trying to access in the dd($users)? or in dd($users->usermeta)?

Comment: Yes i can check plz this dump http://echome.in/user.html 
I even changed the meta_key to `nickname` as that was what available at 0th position , but still it returns null

Comment: The model attributes for `Usermeta` are `meta_key` and `meta_value`. You should be able to access `$user->usermeta[0]->meta_key` and `$user->usermeta[0]->meta_value` but `first_name` is not a attribute on `usermeta`, so $user->usermeta[0]->first_name will return `null`.

Comment: To use `meta_key` and `meta_value` as a key value pair, you could write an accessor method on `User`. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: This works, except for the records that have null `meta_value` for `meta_key` it returns `undefined offset 0` error. How to handle this error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80753/discussion-between-james-flight-and-echoashu).